# QGIS GDAL Installation Error

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation

I am using a Mac OS High Sierra, version 10.13.6.

While installing the more recent version of QGIS, I ran into a popup that said "Failure, The GDAL 2.3 framework is required."

Naturally, I opened up terminal, and entered tried to bash install GDAL, but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
sudo pip3 install GDAL
```

gives me

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-g7dpscpt/GDAL/
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Seems like GDAL isnt installed, did you read the readme? Pretty sure you need to install Python first, then GDAL, then QGIS. All the installers come in the dmg if i remember correctly

Answer (score 1):

You may try more user friendly installer without readme and other instruction for advanced users. Just next -> next -> finish. But in this installer only previous QGIS LTR present - 2.18.25. 
You can get installer here: http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/

There is autoupdate tool in this installer, so as soon 3.x version will be ready, notification will popup.

**Disclaimer**: I'm developer at NextGIS.